# System.out.println in static initializer apparently outputting twice

Tags: java

In my application deployed on Tomcat, there is a class as follows:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public abstract class ServiceEndpointApplication extends Application {

    final static String LOGGER_NAME = "test";

    static {
        System.out.println("static init start");
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);
        logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        System.out.println("static init end");
    }
    ...
}
```

Just after starting up Tomcat, I send 50 reqests by using JMeter (50 threads, 1 ramp-up period, 1 loop).

Then `tail -f catalina.out` shows the following logs:

```
Nov 06, 2018 1:36:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 64126 ms
static init start
static init end
static init end
```

`static init end` is shown twice!

This behavior happens at a probability of about 10%.

**My Question**:

What are possible reasons for this strange behavior?

**Environment**:

- Java

  - java version "1.7.0_80"
  - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
  - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
- Tomcat 7.0.59

Comment: Is there a chance that you print `"static init end"` from some other place in code?

Comment: No. After I changed the message to a new message, then the new message was shown twice.

Comment: Only explanation I can think of is this some strange problem with buffer or very strong black magic used to mess with threads that allow to duplicate thread while running.

Comment: If you remove code between `println` does problem reproduces?

Comment: I have one more, more realistic, hypothesis. Tomcat replace `PrintWriter` in `System.out`. This new `PrintWriter` have some problem in it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm trying removing the code and testing now.

Comment: try to print thread name in logs so that you can see which thread print the statements

Comment: Could you additionally print out the current Thread, the context classloader and the System.out itself? `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " "  + Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() + " " + System.out + " static init start/end" );`

Comment: @Deadpool Okay. I will try it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I wrote the reason as my answer, and it may disappoint you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason. This is caused by `-f` option of `tail` command.

I reproduced this behavior:

```
$ tail -f catalina.out
  ...
Nov 06, 2018 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 62601 ms
static init start
static init end
static init end
```

And then I ran `tail` without any options:

```
$ tail catalina.out 
  ...
Nov 06, 2018 7:18:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 62601 ms
static init start
static init end
```